# Compare variable string in XSLT with IF condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm using a variable in XSLT that is returned from JAVA code which i'm assigning to a variable and comparing it with a string. I am able to successfully print the variable with `<xsl:value-of select="$errorMessage" />` but unable to satisfy the IF condition.

Below is my XSL

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="errorMessage">$CONTEXT{parameters.customeErrorMessage}</xsl:variable>
        <h1><xsl:value-of select="$errorMessage" /></h1>
        <xsl:if test="(contains($errorMessage, 'PAGE_NOT_FOUND'))">
            <h2> The requested page is not found </h2>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$errorMessage= 'PAGE_NOT_AVAILABLE_IN_LANGUAGE'">
            <h2> Page does not exist in language </h2>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<h1>PAGE_NOT_FOUND</h1>
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of the output of `$errorMessage`?

Comment: Updated the post with output

Comment: Which XSLT processor is that exactly? What kind of data type do you have on the Java side? How is the Java value converted to XSLT/XPath values?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would expect to see the test `test="$errorMessage = 'PAGE_NOT_FOUND'"` rather than `test="(contains($errorMessage, 'PAGE_NOT_FOUND'))"`. But that's probably not going to solve the problem.

The stylesheet is clearly dependent on some non-standard mechanism to evaluate `$CONTEXT{parameters.customeErrorMessage}`, and I'm not familiar with that mechanism -- you need to tell us more about the processor you are using and the environment in which it is executed. I suspect that this expression is returning some kind of Java object that doesn't behave quite like an XPath string; specifically, `xsl:value-of` outputs a string representation of the object, but the `contains()` function isn't converting it to a string in the same way. But this is very speculative.

Comment: Looks like the text is not received as string from Java. I just tried using ' <h1><xsl:value-of select="string-length($errorMessage)" /></h1>'  and got the output as 40 instead of 14 for string 'PAGE_NOT_FOUND' . is there any option to convert to string in XSLT?

Comment: Martin and I have both explained that to help you further, we need to know what technology you are using and how the data is passed from Java into the XSLT.